# Converting uint8_t to String - unexpected result

Tags: esp8266, string

I'm working on a remote control code for ESP controller. Using ESPwebserver and Fastled. When I try to return a value of an uint8_t, as a POST response, i got strange result here is the relevant code:

```
uint8_t PaletteBrightness = 255; 

server.on("/Sync", HTTP_POST, []() {
String Sync = "PaletteBrightness:" + PaletteBrightness;
    Sync += ":end";
    Serial.println(Sync);
    server.send(200, "text/plain", Sync);
  });
```

The code complies, and runs fine but the result of 'Sync' in both serial, and POST response is:

```
Phase:end
```

Why? What does even Phase mean?
What I want is:

```
PaletteBrightness:255:end
```

Where the 255 is the value of 'uint8_t PaletteBrightness' Also, there will be more values, to add the 'Sync' string. Just trying to get one right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your number `uint8_t` into it's ASCII representation before appending it to your string, otherwise you are appending just one character using it's byte representation.

To do so you can use a standard function `itoa()` which has a decent documentation available [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/).

So change line

```
 String Sync = "PaletteBrightness:" + PaletteBrightness;
```

into

```
 char buffer [4];
 String Sync = "PaletteBrightness:" + itoa(PaletteBrightness, buffer, 10);
```

Comment: I've ended up using 
   String(PaletteBrightness); And it seems to do the trick. Would it be better to use itoa()?

Comment: Avoid the use of `String` at all costs unless there absolutely no alternative. https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/

Comment: Will read this trough. I need to send and receive data from client which is done in http post, effectively plain text. Don't think there is a way around strings there.

Comment: Yes, there is at least another way: array of chars. And before you ask, strings **are not** just array of chars, remember you are dealing with C here, not Java or JavaScript. Also memory is a big constraint, anything that is dynamically allocated must be strictly controlled and memory fragmentation can quickly become an issue.

Comment: Okay, I read up on String, and now i understand a bit better why are they bad. However, [ESP8266WebServer.h](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer)  
Uses lots of Strings, and related String object functions. Isnt that also wrong? or I'm missing some key elements here.

Comment: Probably the code you are referring to was meant as an introductory or learning (may be both?) resource... As such the author did use strings to make it easier to understand for people coming from other languages (Java, JavaScript,etc...)... Please also note he is using references to, at least, minimize the impact of using strings. Also, ESP8266 has much more SRAM than an ATmega328 (Arduino), which somewhat mitigates the problem. And in any case, the fact somebody else has done something _not good_ does not justify you doing the same mistake...

Comment: Make sense, I re wrote the entire code, http://pastebin.com/8aQdhgdQ 
Hopefully its better now. Also found reserve(); function, so When i figure out how many byte  is the final string, it should be good enough. Any opinion?